# JTextPane scroll to specific row

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I am trying to scroll JTextPane to specific line. For doing that, i put my text pane into the JScrollPane as JViewport. I determine the x and y coordinates of the line with :

```
JViewport port = (JViewport)getParent();
JScrollPane pane = (JScrollPane)port.getParent();
float calculated = (float)i/(float)lines.size() * 100;
pane.getVerticalScrollBar().setMaximum(100);
pane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue((int)calculated);
```

With this code block, i can scroll the scrollbar but i can not scroll the context of text area. Only scrollbar moves, but displaying text seems the same as before. I need to display the line which is calculated.(By the way calculated variable is between 0-100)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Text Utilities](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/26/text-utilities/) class.

You can use the `gotoStartOfLine(...)` method to position the caret at the beginning of a line. This will cause the text area to scroll if required.

Or maybe you can use the `centerLineInScrollPane(...)` method.

Comment: This is not working because my document text is html